# Apache Hive string splitting

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata

There is this table consisting of only one column which is a string.i want to split each row using ',' and then put these in a seperate table using Apache Hive .How should i do this ?

Comment: Did you try reading the hive documentation? https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF

Answer (score 2):

A very easy way would be to:

```
create table database.new_table as
select split(col_value,',')[0] as column_1 
, split(col_value,',')[1] as column_2
, split(col_value,',')[2] as column_3
-- and so no till your nth column
, split(col_value,',')[10]as column_11 
from database.oldtable;
```

All the columns will be of type string.  If you want the columns to be something other than string than cast it like below:

```
, select cast(split(col_value,',')[2] as double) as column_3
```

You can cast any data type that hive offers, int, bigint, double...

With Subquery

```
create table database.new_table as
select A[0] as column_1,
       A[1] as column_2
       -- and so on till your nth column
from (
    select split(col_value,',') as A 
    from database.oldtable ) x;
```

Comment: Would it be better to use a single call to split with a subquery?

Comment: @ fivetentaylor, you are correct.  I did a poor job of cutting and pasting in my asnwer and left those extra calls. I have edited the answer to be correct.  Also, if this answer works for please select as answer.  Many thanks.

Comment: Hey @invoketheshell, I added an edit to your answer to show what I was thinking.  Feel free to hack it up however you'd like.  Thanks!